# C++ Loading a DLL into the default AppDomain

Tags: .net, winapi, unmanaged, managed, code-injection

Using my non-existent knowledge of C++ (hey, at least I know what a pointer is :P ), I managed to throw together some code samples to create a solution that will inject a DLL file into another program.

Unfortunately, it's the DLL I'm INJECTING that's not working properly: it successfully displays the messageboxes (so I know the DLL is running), but it's not actually creating the instance of the specified type (from the managed DLL, which has a static constructor in type Injectee that writes to a file). So, can anyone help me with where I'm going wrong? (N.B. the managed DLL is the same .Net version, and installed to the GAC. There's also a copy in the same folder as the application I'm injecting into)

This is the unmanaged injectee (that's supposed to load the managed DLL):

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include "Injectee.h"

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include "objbase.h"
#include "MSCorEE.h"
#import "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.tlb" raw_interfaces_only
using namespace mscorlib;

void Bootstrap() {
    CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED );
    ICorRuntimeHost* pICorRuntimeHost = 0;
    HRESULT st = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CorRuntimeHost, 0, CLSCTX_ALL,
        IID_ICorRuntimeHost, (void**)&pICorRuntimeHost);
    if(!pICorRuntimeHost) {
        MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Failed at stage 1."), TEXT("Error"), MB_OK); 
    }

    HDOMAINENUM hEnum = NULL;
    pICorRuntimeHost->EnumDomains(&hEnum);

    if(!hEnum) {
        MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Failed at stage 2."), TEXT("Error"), MB_OK); 
    }

    IUnknown* pUunk = 0;
    st = pICorRuntimeHost->NextDomain(hEnum, &pUunk);
    if(!pUunk) {
        MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Failed at stage 3."), TEXT("Error"), MB_OK); 
    }

    _AppDomain * pCurDomain = NULL;
    st = pUunk->QueryInterface(__uuidof(_AppDomain), (VOID**)&pCurDomain);
    if(!pCurDomain) {
        MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Failed at stage 4."), TEXT("Error"), MB_OK); 
    }

    _bstr_t assemblyName = "ZAI, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9db2aaea0fceabbb";
    _bstr_t typeName = "Injectee";

    _ObjectHandle* pObjectHandle = 0;

    MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Loading DLL."), TEXT("Error"), MB_OK); 

    pCurDomain->CreateInstance(assemblyName, typeName, &pObjectHandle);
}
```

Any help?

(Note, managed assembly is built against both architectures (target app is x64), has base namespace ZAI))

Any advice is appreciated.

(In case you're wondering, I'm trying to add an API to a freeware, closed-source .Net app)

Comment: Loading the CLR twice in the same process is not possible, at least with version 2.  Since you didn't get an error, at least part of the problems ought to be that you didn't actually inject the DLL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine that creating a new `CorRuntimeHost` instance creates a new AppDomain.

I would suggest writing a mixed-mode C++/CLI DLL and injecting that.

---

If you've confirmed you did get a reference to the right AppDomain, call `AppDomain::Load` before `CreateInstance`.  Or even `AppDomain::ExecuteAssembly`, if you set the entry point of your assembly to do something useful.

Comment: I need to run my managed code inside the AppDomain that everything else in the program is in (it only has one AppDomain, checked that). And just in case you didn't realise, the code above is the unmanaged, Win32 DLL that I have successfully injected into said program (messagebox on DLL_ATTACH proves it).

Comment: Voigt I'm having trouble achieving what you mentioned in your edit. Can you point me to some useful documentation? I'm having trouble finding any...

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sxx9f4c2.aspx or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4cw969y.aspx

Comment: Cheers! Thanks to your references and advice, I've managed to get this all working! I'd buy you a drink, if I could. ;)

Comment: Liam Dawson, in your last comment you have mentioned that you have managed to get it work. Can you please add how you resolved in your question itself so that it will help me and others?